# jQuery draggable, only snap to grid within parent

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

```
-------------------------------
|                             |
|             box             |
|                             |
-------------------------------

---------
| thing |
---------
```

I want `thing` to be able to be dragged freely around until it is dragged into `box`. When it is being dragged within `box`, I want it to snap to a grid (say 20px*20px for example).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use [containment](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-containment) option as follows

```
$( ".selector" ).draggable({
  containment: "parent"
});
```

Or you can set as follows in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BYsnc/).

```
$('#floor').droppable({
    tolerance: 'fit'
});

$('#drag').draggable({
    revert: 'invalid',
    stop: function(){
        $(this).draggable('option','revert','invalid');
    }
});

$('#drag').droppable({
    greedy: true,
    tolerance: 'touch',
    drop: function(event,ui){
        ui.draggable.draggable('option','revert',true);
    }
});
```